# How to install ggtern package in R

Tags: r

I ran the following code in R according to [this page](http://www.ggtern.com/installation/)

```
install.packages("ggtern")
```

but R says

```
> install.packages("ggtern")
Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning message:
package ‘ggtern’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

Now how can I install it?

**Just for the sake of completeness:**

1. `> install.packages(c("ggplot2", "plyr", "gtable", "scales", "reshape2", "proto", "sp"))`
2. Download `ggtern_1.0.3.2.tar.gz` from `http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggtern/` and put it on `Home` directory or ran
   `download.file("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggtern/ggtern_1.0.3.2.tar.gz", destfile="ggtern_1.0.3.2.tar.gz")`.
3. `> install.packages("ggtern_1.0.3.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL)`.
4. Load the package `> library(ggtern)`.
5. Use the package. See [Making a ternary plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439123/making-a-ternary-plot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `ggtern` was removed from the CRAN repository (Archived on 2015-03-03 as misuse of `\donttest` was not corrected).

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the [archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggtern/).

You can install the source package manually in R:

```
R> download.file("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggtern/ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz",
                 destfile="ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz")
R> install.packages("ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

or in a shell:

```
sh> wget "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggtern/ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz"
sh> R CMD INSTALL ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz
```

Comment: `install.packages("ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz", repos=NULL)` 
`Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’` 
`(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)` 
`ERROR: dependencies ‘ggplot2’, ‘plyr’, ‘gtable’, ‘scales’, ‘reshape2’, ‘proto’, ‘sp’ are not available for package ‘ggtern’` 
`* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/ggtern’` 
`Warning message:` 
`In install.packages("ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL) :` 
`installation of package ‘ggtern_1.0.1.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: install the missing packages from CRAN first: `install.packages(c("ggplot2", "sp"))`

Comment: ggtern (version 1.0.5 ) is on CRAN again: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/2015/04/15/#ggtern_1.0.5.0